# Javascript not loading in child page (Inherit from master page)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm currently trying to use a JS function in my child page, which is loaded in the master page, but it doesn't work.

I've tried adding the scripts again, before calling them, which works, but it's unnecessary as it should already be loaded.

ManageKey.aspx

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="ManageKey.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="PlisSmartSuiteLicenseToolsWebsite.Pages.ManageKey" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="contentPanel" Visible="false">
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panelKeySelected" Visible="false">
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="checkBoxAllDetails" runat="server" 
                    Text="Show All Details" style="text-align: center;"
                    OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxAllDetails_CheckedChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true"/>
            </div>
            <div class="row newCustomer-container">
                <div id="licenseKeyInformationDiv" class="col-sm-10" 
                    style="text-align: center; overflow-x: auto; white-space: 
                        nowrap; margin-left: 8.33%; margin-right:1rem;">                
                    <asp:GridView id="licenseKeyInformationGridView"
                        CssClass="tablesorter"
                        OnPreRender="licenseKeyInformationGridView_PreRender" 
                        OnRowDataBound="LicenseKeyInformationGridView_RowDataBound" 
                        CellPadding="3" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField Runat="server" DataField="ID"
                                HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" >
                            </asp:BoundField>
                        </Columns>
                        <HeaderStyle />
                    </asp:GridView>                

                    <script type="text/javascript" 
                        src="~/../../Scripts/tablesorter_documentready.js"">
                    </script>

                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Site.Master

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="PlisSmartSuiteLicenseToolsWebsite.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title><%: Page.Title %> - PLIS License Management</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/CustomerStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/css/theme.grey.min.css" integrity="sha256-oWElaGouUGQjjUj4NJOPJfu02uNGlUnwp+GrwEKTA44=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" integrity="sha256-uC1JMW5e1U5D28+mXFxzTz4SSMCywqhxQIodqLECnfU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js" integrity="sha256-46l1q40VwOPnofvWNG4vQuFjxEnidAIBBn75kgKnI6c=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
```

Addingthe scripttags for JQuery and tablesorter above the script i'm importing works, but I want to avoid that.

The console just prints that tablesorter() is not a function.

Note: it works on other pages.
Edit: I cut down the code for readability, it's way larger but the amount of div's are right.

Comment: I know is a good practice putting the script tag at the end of the body, but, can you try, just for curiosity, putting those 3 script tags in the <head> of your master page?

Comment: You are calling `tablesorter()` before the external resources are available. Hence the `tablesorter()` is not a function. It is hard to tell without the relevant parts of your `tablesorter_documentready.js"` script

Comment: Also where is the `MainContent` place holder on your master page?

Comment: As I have less than 50Rep I could not able to comment on your post, sorry for that You have used CDN's(Content Delivery Network), do you have an Internet connection in your Computer where you have Implemented above Page??

Comment: @Jon - The tablesorter_documentready is just calling the script using Jquery for when the page is finished loading, so it should be available by that time.

Comment: Yes, the CDN isn't an issue, as it works fine if I put them right before my script as well. Also, it works fine on all other pages than this one.

Comment: @Andres2141 - The tags are already in the head tag.

Comment: @JonP The maincontent placeholder is in the body of my master page.

Comment: The first link in your master isn't closed properly.

Comment: @wazz Fixed, but has made no change. Also fixed it in the child where I had an extra ".

Answer (score 0):

Worth a look as it helped me with this issue: [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/534587/asp-net-jquery-is-not-working-in-updatepanels)

Async postbacks from the update panel ruins event handlers when content is returned - the solution refreshes those so you can use them.